# Thread aborted in parallel web test with MSTEST and Selenium

Tags: multithreading, selenium, automated-tests, mstest, selenium-grid

I'm on the last mile getting this to work.

I have multiple tests running at once in my test project by changing the parallelTestCount setting in Local.testsettings:

```
  <Execution parallelTestCount="5">
    <TestTypeSpecific />
    <AgentRule name="Execution Agents">
    </AgentRule>
  </Execution>
```

I installed hot fix KB2619410 to resolve issues with the parallel tests in VS.

In `UnitTesting.AssemblyInitialize()` I start the Selenium Server hub and node. I kill these processes in `UnitTesting.AssemblyCleanup()`.

```
java -jar C:\...\selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar -role hub
java -jar C:\...\selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=chrome,maxInstances=5,platform=WINDOWS
```

I spawn 5 threads to create the `RemoteWebDriver` instances and log in to my web site

```
    Dim desiredCapabilities As Remote.DesiredCapabilities = Remote.DesiredCapabilities.Chrome()
    Dim size As String = "--window-size={0},{1}"
    size = String.Format(size, browserWidth, browserHeight)
    Dim position As String = "--window-position={0},{1}"
    position = String.Format(position, browserWidth * index, 0)
    desiredCapabilities.SetCapability("chrome.switches", {size, position})
    driver = New Remote.RemoteWebDriver(New System.Uri("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), desiredCapabilities)
    ...
    ...code to use driver to log into web site
```

I join the threads so that the testing does not begin until they are all logged in. I created a DriverPoolManger class to assign available web drivers to waiting tests. Whenever I check to see if a driver is available, or change it's status, I use a ReaderWriterLock:

```
    _readerWriterLock.AcquireWriterLock(Threading.Timeout.Infinite)
    _locks(index) = False
    _readerWriterLock.ReleaseWriterLock()
```

At this point, it ran the tests in parallel for a while and then failed with:

```
Type is not resolved for member 'OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException,WebDriver, Version=2.16.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1c2bd1631853048f'.
```

After some research the solution was to copy the dlls it was looking for into a new folder called "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\UnitTestAssemblies", and then updating QTAgent32.exe.config to list this in the privatePath:

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <probing privatePath="PrivateAssemblies;PublicAssemblies;DataCollectors;DataCollectors\x64;PrivateAssemblies\DataCollectors;PrivateAssemblies\DataCollectors\x64;UnitTestAssemblies;"/>
</assemblyBinding>
```

Now, the tests run for a while, and then my `UnitTesting.AssemblyCleanup()` proc runs unexpectedly and kills all the browsers and Selenium Server. VSTTExecution logs the following error:

```
(QTAgent32.exe, PID 8444, Thread 15) Unit Test Adapter threw exception: System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestExecuter.RunTestMethod()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestExecuter.ExecuteTest()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestExecuter.Execute(UnitTestResult result)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestRunner.ExecuteSingleTest(UnitTestExecuter executer, UnitTestElement test, ITestContext testContext, UnitTestAdapterContext userContext, Boolean isLoadTest)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestRunner.Run(UnitTestElement test, ITestContext testContext, Boolean isLoadTest, Boolean useMultipleCpus)
```

I'm going to try it without the driver pool, but that means starting up a new driver and logging in for each test. I don't have a ton of experience with mult-threading, and there seems to be alot of issues with parallel tests in VS. Could my driver pool be causing this?

**Update:**
I removed my driver pool, and this problem is still occuring.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I almost gave up, but here is the solution:

mstest /noisolation

This eliminates qtagent32.exe altogether, and I haven't had problems since.